# WebScrapping con Python

Tags: python, web, python-requests, beautifulsoup, requests

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en hacer un programa de web scrapping con Python. Utilizo las librerias requests y BeautifulSoup. El caso es que para llegar hasta la página donde estan los datos que me interesan, hay que tramitar varias peticiones POST, hacer click en algunos botones, etc. He visto que con Selenium se puede interactuar con un navegador web y hacerlo, pero me gustaria hacerlo sin necesidad de hacerlo mediante navegador. Alguien conoce cual es la mejor manera o si existe alguna libreria que permita hacerlo?

Comment: Con `requests.Session()` no te está funcionando?

Comment: Estoy usando la libreria requests, pero no he probado de levantar una sesión como tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usualmente, usamos selenium para hacer scraping de contenido "dinámico" por ejemplo ventanas emergentes con JS, si este no es el caso puedes hacerlo con BeatutifulSoup y Requests.

Puedo sugerir algunas recomendaciones:

1. Crear una función para automatizar el scraping.
2. ¿Has intentado acceder directamente al link que buscas? ¿Podrías mostrarnos a que sitio le estás haciendo scraping? De este modo puedo dar una respuesta mas específica.

Que herramienta uses depende mucho del problema y la solución que esperas,pero de forma popular y mas robusta se usa  [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Comment: Buenas Matias, he creado una función para automatizar el scraping. No puedo acceder al link que busco directamente, pues es un link temporal con una URL que se genera con parámetros dinámicos. Para que te hagas una idea es un link de compra de entradas, en el que quiero comprovar disponibilidades. 

Los pasos son los siguientes:

1- Acceder página principal.
2- Click al botón de entradas.
3- Se abre una pestaña nueva con la disponibilidad de entradas(URL con parámetros dinámicos).

Comment: Hasta donde llegan mis conocimientos, si lo que intentas es hacer scraping de contenido dinamico lo mejor es selenium. Quizas antes de optar por esa opcion puedes fijarte en la url, muchas veces la url se forma asi:

https://www.dominio.com/sub-pagina?PARAMETROS. y puedas construir la url de forma "dinamica" si no es el caso deberas continuar con selenium.

Comment: La url es más o menos como dices, el caso es que los parametros se componen de una serie de identificadores temporales(entiendo que lo hacen porque es la forma de saber que hay una compra en curso) que no se muy bien de donde salen, y por ese motivo soy incapaz de concatenar yo por script la url final. Probaré con Selenium si no hay alternativa, lo que más me preocupa es si podré utilitzarlo también en un dipositivo android. Gracias por la ayuda!!